# AngularJS - add active class to itself after click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is there a simple declarative way (without a additional function in the $scope) to marked clicked element with AngularJS?

e.g. I have a button which I want to marked as clicked/checked.

```
<button ng-model="form.btn" ng-click=" // do stuff here to add a class or attr ">Go</button>
```

I was able to achieve this with external function but I am looking for a declarative way / all in HTML template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<button ng-model="form.btn" ng-click="form.btn = true" 
ng-class="{'active' : form.btn}">
    Go
</button>
```

Comment: That assumes that form.btn will be bool value, string will fail here, please extend it to be more generic ;)

Comment: Yes - string would be very useful, would be great to have this inside a ng-repeat with an array like ['yes', 'no']

Answer (score 4):

If you want toggle class use this: [http://jsbin.com/vimero/1/edit](http://jsbin.com/vimero/2/edit)

```
<button ng-model="btn" ng-click="btn =! btn" ng-class="{'active' : btn}"> 
 Toogle 
</button>
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is going on here? This `btn =! btn` looks very mysterious .

Comment: @User789 it change from true to false and false to true. It's a toggle. But it should be `btn = !btn;`

Answer (score 1):

`ng-click="yourFunction($event.target)"`

And do your transformations in `yourFunction`. You'll have HTMLElement passed as 1st param.

Answer (score 1):

I found this works pretty well for a group of buttons to toggle active **ng-class** if the condition set in **ng-click** is met:

```
<button ng-class="{'active' : activeButton == 'firstButton'} ng-click="activeButton = 'firstButton'>
  First Button
</button>
<button ng-class="{'active' : activeButton == 'secondButton'} ng-click="activeButton = 'secondButton'>
  Second Button
</button>
<button ng-class="{'active' : activeButton == 'thirdButton'} ng-click="activeButton = 'thirdButton'>
  Third Button
</button>
```